# Can I edit fields of an hibernate entity inside the class (for example some domain logic) or can it lead to some proxy related issues?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I know Hibernate uses proxies under the hood and I know for example that Spring-data uses proxies for transactions and there are limitation with @Transaction Annotation (if method1 from Class A calls method2 with @Transaction Annotation from Class A, then the Annotation will have no effect). So my question is are there some similar limitation in Hibernate? Because I want implement some part of my domain logic inside the Hibernate-Entity class and for this I must be sure that my methods can modify the fields (primitives/other entities/collections of entities) inside the class without any problems related to Hibernate. See code as an example.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long id;

  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String email;

  public void doChange() {
    doChangePrivate();
  }

  private void doChangePrivate() {
    email = "asdf@a.com";
  }
}

... 
start Transaction inside a Service-Class
... myentity.doChange();
```

I tried this out and it worked. But can some issues occure (related to hibernate) if I write some part of my domain logic inside the hibernate-entity class that modifies the fields (primitives/entities/colletion of entities) inside a transaction?

Comment: I think for porpeties which are not associations or Collections,hibernate loads them at loading,so you shouldn't have proexies for String fields in your example.Proxies are made for your Entity Classes,and the only place where hibernate can put lazy loading checks is in getter methods.Since properties that are not associations or collections are loaded by default,i think you shouldn't have any problem.In general you should use getters whenever possible to avoid any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a post about something similar (https://thoughts-on-java.org/access-strategies-in-jpa-and-hibernate/) and it looks like I am allowed to do this if I use field-based access (see Reason 5 in the post). Can someone confirm this?